# How to void closing Mac's screen when using mianloop()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am a novice and learn something by myself.So many problems occour.I want to make a simple GUI through tkinter. But when I use mianloop(), the screen is closed. Just like I close the WindowsServer. I use Spyder.
I try to copy others codes and run it in my ide. I failed.

```
# python3.7.4 MacOS 10.14.6
import requests
import re
import tkinter as tk

url = 'http://www.qmaile.com/'
a = requests.get(url)
a.enconding = a.apparent_encoding
b = a.text
reg = re.compile('<option value="(.*?)" selected="">')
res = re.findall(reg, b)
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()  # My screen is closed.
```

I expect I can see a interface ,but the screen is closed.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on a Mac. I see a blank window pop up, as I would expect.

Comment: Thank you.Does this issue have anything to do with the version that comes with the system? I downloaded and used Anaconda directly. No settings have been changed.Maybe I need to installed and installed again.

Comment: I don't know. I've never used anaconda.